# how to put messageCell at bottom of tableView? *Swift*

Tags: ios, swift

Chat set up. messagetableView bottom constraint attached to top of dockView. Unfortunately the tableView messageCell doesn't conform to the same constraint forced on the tableView. In my screenshot you can see the yellow tableView. It starts at the top of the superView and extends down to the top of the UIViewDock. The white messageCell does not follow the tableView. Obviously the messageCell is doing this because there are only 5 rows of messages so how do I make the white cell start at the bottom of the tableView like chat apps do?

Someone in another old thread said to use this Obj-C.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL shouldScrollToLastRow;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

_shouldScrollToLastRow = YES;
}


- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

// Scroll table view to the last row
if (_shouldScrollToLastRow)
{
    _shouldScrollToLastRow = NO;
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
}
}
```

Is this correct and how would I do it in Swift?

[image]

Comment: Possible solution, not really enough details to warrant making it an answer, but you could flip your `UITableView` upside down. Then your cells would start at the bottom and work their way towards the top. When you go to add cells, you can always add them at the first position. On another note, several mobile messing apps don't keep messages on the bottom. They work just as your does now.

Comment: Hi. I am using Line, WeChat, QQ and HelloTalk and they all start at the bottom with old messages at the top. iMessage does seem to function like you said with new messages starting at the top but even iMessage messages end up at the bottom if you've filled the screen with messages. I want that look because I think it's more natural to be able to see the history above the new text. ** I could be ok with doing it the iMessage way BUT then I have other issues because in my app the dock and tableView have to be able to move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your messageCell the footer of the table view so it will always stick to the bottom of the table. You can add a view to the table in IB, and give it an IBOutlet (I call mine footer in the code below).

```
    @IBOutlet weak var footer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.rowHeight = 44
        tableView.tableFooterView = footer
        tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: tableView.contentSize.height), animated: false)
    }
```

In the "Send" button's action method, you can do this to add a new row and keep the table scrolled to the bottom,

```
@IBAction func sendMessage(sender: UIButton) {
        var message = messageField.text
        messages.append(message)
        let lastPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: messages.count - 1, inSection: 0)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([lastPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView.contentSize = CGSize(width: tableView.contentSize.width, height: tableView.contentSize.height + tableView.rowHeight)
        tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: tableView.contentSize.height), animated: true)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

Comment: @Ringo, I guess. Whatever that is at the bottom with the camera image and Send button. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Ringo, do you have another viewDidLoad implementation in the same file?

Comment: @Ringo, I'm not talking about the whole app, just this one view controller. You can only have one viewDidLoad in any one controller.

Comment: @Ringo, no, you should put it in the one implementation of viewDidLoad that you have. If you have more than one, then consolidate all the code into one, and get rid of the other one.

Comment: @Ringo That code shouldn't have done that. You must have deleted something else that mattered.

Comment: @Ringo, yes, you add a view to the table view, and add any subviews (with their constraints) to it.  Those constraints should only be for the subviews of the footer view. The footer shouldn't have any constraints to its superview (which is the table view).

Comment: @Ringo DocView is not a subview of your table. It needs to be.

Comment: @Ringo, Ignore what it looks like in the storyboard. By setting it as the table view's footer view in code, it will be placed at the bottom as it should.

Comment: @Ringo  Did you connect the outlet for footer? If not, the code in viewDidLoad won't work, and the default is to make that view a header.

Comment: Hi. I'm back after dinner and ready to tackle it. I am doing the second block you taught me. 3 screens. [iPhone live] http://i.imgur.com/c8IAQoI.gifv  __|||__  [outline]  http://i.imgur.com/ECgMShO.png   __|||__   [code]  http://i.imgur.com/wsNOQiu.png

Comment: outlet for footer? Yup I did that a while back. The code for it is in my viewDidLoad. |||||    http://i.imgur.com/nd7nEKT.png ||||| http://i.imgur.com/a5vH8be.png  |||||

Comment: @Ringo, It seems the order of the views in the scene list matters. Drag the messageCell above DockView,, and it should work.

Comment: It worked!!  You know what. I actually knew the order mattered BUT Xcode layout has a a little quirk. If you touch an UIImageView for example on the storyboard to adjust something like a constraint, sometimes that object will fall below the one under or over it. They need to fix this in Xcode. As well as make it possible to hide and lock "layers" like other design apps. Thank you so much for your patience with a noob like me.

Comment: you don't by chance take Paypal for casual private tutoring do you? Like charging by the email or hourly rate? I'm serious.